# Retrieve git information without retrieving file contents

Tags: git

I want to access information from a git repository, such as the commit list and existing branches, without downloading the contents of the files. Is it possible to clone a simpler version of a repository, or to delete files from the .git folder which contain this information?

Comment: As the git gurus explain, everything is blob in git [see here](http://git-scm.com/book/no-nb/v1/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) Files are a consequence of the information not a separated stuff.

Comment: So basically you want a database with the repository metadata without files and diffs but giving access to the repository information in a fast way?

Comment: From [stackoverflow.com/q/13941976], you can show the log of a specific remote branch with `git log remotename/branchname`

Comment: @syfn in order to do a git log I need to have a local copy of the whole repo, I am trying to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

You can get all refs (branches, tags) with `git ls-remote <repo-url>`:

```
$ git ls-remote https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git
<snip>
35ddc8427ed664241cf5a4b87cfd2d7d6ce70697        refs/heads/derp
d940f7cd851b77b16315a25b41424f2e14bcef90        refs/heads/gh-pages
61415d8bb19e23c4ee5d6641486a60055c1a8945        refs/heads/grunt-contrib-htmlmin
fd35779f0e15df27a8a05459a000d84320d8bb00        refs/heads/input-group-sizes-glyphicon
420a8088a4086cf06d930070404531cba8db8a8d        refs/heads/master
<snip looooooots of refs>
c52368d3c5984b28e6a71e5e1240afdd788fc2e6        refs/tags/v2.1.1^{}
262a778771929ac8812fb000496febcb605c813d        refs/tags/v2.2.0
b5af762ef59e1fa97f4386f5feadb67aa5183fef        refs/tags/v2.2.0^{}
<snip>
```

I'm fairly certain that you cannot get the commits.

If you're interested in the current files but don't want to clone everything, you can do a shallow clone with `git clone --depth 1 <repo-url>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but `ls-remote` only gives me the HEAD of each branch. I would also like to access the commit list of a branch for example

Comment: @nmat Yes, well, I addressed this.